# meteor call inside another meteor call

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have a meteor call structure as shown :

```
Meteor.call('method1', function(err, result){
    //do something
    Meteor.call('method2', function(err, result){
        //do something
    })
    ...
})
```

The 'method2' sometimes does not been called. I tried a solution by adding "setTimeout" for 'method2', but after 2 weeks, the method2 dose not been called randomly again.

Anyone has any clue for that? Thank you for your help.

More details about my code:

1) there are two servers connected by cluster, and they are named as server1 and server2

2) Meteor methods defined in server1 are named server1_method1 and server1_method2

3) Meteor methods defined in server2 are named server2_method1 and server2_method2

//client of server1

```
Meteor.call("server1_method1", function(err, result){
   if(result){
       Meteor.call("server1_method2", function(err,result){
            //do something
       })
   }
})
```

//server of server1

```
var server2 = Cluster.discoverConnection('server2');

Meteor.methods({
   'server1_method1':function(){
       server2.call('server2_method1', function(err, result){ //where problem happens
          if(result){
             server2.call('server2_method2', function(err, result){
               if(result){
                   //do something
               }    
             })
          }    
       })
       }

})
```

//server of server2

```
Meteor.methods({
   'server2_method1':function(){
       //do something like collect data from database
   },
   'server2_method2':function(){
       //do something like collect data from database
   }
})
```

The server2 calls the 'server2_method1' does not trigger the methods occasionally.

Comment: What does the first method do?

Comment: @AdamWolski Actually the first method can do anything. In my project, the first method is used to detect if an input account exists. The second method detect the password if the account exists.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for the result of the first call to make the second, like this:

```
Meteor.call('method1', function(err, result){
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
      }

    if (result){
        Meteor.call('method2', function(err2, result2){
        //do something
       })
   }
})
```

Consider also other variable names for the second call arguments if you plan to use the first call variables within the second call block

Comment: Thanks @Billybobbonnet for your comments. I have done what you suggested. But the method2 still does not work occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

On server 1, your `server1_method1` should return result synchronously. Thus, a callback of a Cluster call is never called (it is outside of scope)

```
Meteor.methods({
   'server1_method1': function(){
       server2.call('server2_method1', function(err, result){
         // this won't be called as the main server1_method1 needs to 'return' synchronously
       });
       // this Client expects a returned value
       return 'ok';
   }
});
```

You need to convert asynchronous functions to synchronous. Something like this

```
var server2_method1 = Meteor.wrapAsync(function(callback) {
   server2.call('server2_method1', function(err, result){
         callback(err, result);
   });
});
var server2_method1 = Meteor.wrapAsync(function(callback) {
   server2.call('server2_method2', function(err, result){
         callback(err, result);
   });
});
```

And then you can you call them like a synchronous function

```
Meteor.methods({
   'server1_method1': function(){
       var result1 = server2_method1();
       if (result1 == 'something you need') {
         var result2 = server2_method2();
       }
       return 'ok';
   }
});
```

To add params to synchronous functions, put them here like this

```
var server2_method1 = Meteor.wrapAsync(function(param1, param2, callback) {
   server2.call('server2_method1', param1, param2, function(err, result){
         callback(err, result);
   });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call like this.You can use arrguments of first method call in second method call

```
Meteor.call('method1',var1,var2,function(err, result){
if (err) {
   console.log(err);
  }

if (result){
    Meteor.call('method2',var1,var2, function(err2, result2){
    //do something
   })
}
})
```

Comment: @ sravanthi Actually, my problem is the method2 does not work, which means the "//do something" does not been triggered.